# undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass - When trying to run rake db:test:load for the first time

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create some functional tests around my controllers but when I attempt to create the test db I get the error described in my thread. This is the first time I have attempted to populate a test db. I am using the default sqlite adapter. I have populated my fixtures with some test values. Can someone tell me what this error means?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I needed to specifiy the environment to use. This command did the trick: rake db:test:load RAILS_ENV="test"